# Upper bound constraint for several variables in an inequality

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

If I have an inequality of multiple variables, say:

$A+5B+5D+C < 40$

How can I calculate the upper bound constraint for each one of $A, B, C, D$? Given that $A, B, C, D$ must be different.

Thank you.